# xdebug ini settings not applied

Tags: php, chef-infra, xdebug

I was setting up a custom lamp stack with chef on ubuntu 14.04.

The problem is that the settings from xdebug.ini.erb are not applied to php.ini.

I installed xdebug with chef using the package provider package 'php5-xdebug'
after that i have seen xdebug in additional parsed ini files in phpinfo.

I am not totaly shure but i think as soon as i add the line zend_extension = path/xdebug.so xdebug is no longer listed as additional parsed ini file and the settings made to xdebug.ini.erb dont take effect.

**this is the part of my phpinfo xdebug section**

```
xdebug support  enabled
Version     2.2.3
IDE Key     no value

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol     $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

**my xdebug.ini.erb looks like this:**

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.profiler_enable = Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
```

**I can see xdebug is working through the var_dump function which gets a different styling. Only the ini.erb settings not applied.
this is my chef code:**

```
# php5-dev is need for xdebug to have phpize ready
needed = ['php5-mysql', 'php5-mcrypt', 'php-pear', 'php5', 'php5-dev']

additional_packages = ['php5-curl', 'php5-gd', 'php5-intl', 'php5-imagick', 'php5-imap', 'memcached', 'php5-memcached', 'php5-ming', 'php5-xmlrpc', 'php5-xsl', 'php5-xdebug']

needed.each() do |pkg|
    package pkg
end

if node['install']['additional_php_packages'] == true
   additional_packages.each() do |apk|
      package apk
   end
end

template '/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini' do
    source 'xdebug.ini.erb'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to not write a new xdebug.ini but to edit the during install automaticaly generated xdebug.ini with 
Chef::File::Edit and 
insert_line_if_no_match(xdebug.remote_enable = on)

Comment: For other people that find this, use of `FileEdit` is strongly discouraged as it produces very brittle code most of the time. The `line` cookbook offers slightly more robust options, though not by much.

Comment: The root cause is that you create a file in mods-available, not sim-linking it to mods-enabled ... I don't know which distro you use, if your php.ini really include mods-enabled/*  or mods-enabled/*.ini or what is the system state before, but I would bet  your real problem is managing only part of the system with assumptions on how it is before, that's a wrong pattern IMO.

Comment: @Tensibai Installing php5-xdebug creates a xdebug.ini in mods-available and a symlink to that file in php5/apache2/conf.d/ . It could be that just with writing a new ini file chef was clever enough to delete the symlink because it is pointing to different meta data ?  something like a a2enmod in a php way would be great. ;)

Comment: I just think it's a matter of reloading apache at end, which the package install should do...